# Capitalize chapter* in toc with classicthesis

Tags: table-of-contents, capitalization, classicthesis

When adding a chapter entry in the toc, I would like to get it as the other chapters, ie capitalized… For instance, add this line

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Test}
```

between these two lines of ClassicThesis.tex (around line 213 in my version):

```
\cleardoublepage\part{Some Kind of Manual}
\include{Chapters/Chapter01}
```

It tried to modify classicthesis.sty without success by changing (around line 570

```
\newcommand\ChapS[1]{\oldchap*{#1}}%
```

to

```
\newcommand\ChapS[1]{%
  \ifpdf\oldchap*{\texorpdfstring{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{#1}}%
  \else\oldchap*{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}%
  \fi%
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated… Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `classicthesis` package uses `titlesec` to handle its title formatting. `titlesec` strongly discourages the use of starred versions of things.  Instead (as outlined in the `titlesec` documentation) it recommends creating environments for unnumbered sections or chapters. Here's an example that solves your problem.

```
\documentclass[oneside,letterpaper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\newenvironment{unnumbered}%
{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}}
{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A  regular chapter}
\lipsum
\begin{unnumbered}
\chapter{An unnumbered chapter}
\lipsum
\end{unnumbered}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, as I mentioned below it does not change the display of lines added with \addcontentsline. Apparently I missed something when I understood that \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Title} adds a chapter* line in the toc. This is really the behaviour I want to change…

Comment: @Thomas But my solution does exactly that. Unless I'm missing something. You don't need to use the `\addcontentsline` command; the `\chapter{}` command will do that automatically.  Wrapping the chapter in the `unnumbered` environment supresses the number in the chapter just as if you had done `chapter*`.

Comment: Sorry, you're right… I'm getting really too tired! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't modify `classicthesis.sty`: you'll lose either your modifications or improvements of the package in case it's updated.

You can obtain automatic insertion of unnumbered chapters by writing in your document's preamble

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\tableofcontents{
  \renewcommand{\ChapS}[1]{\cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection\oldchap*{#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}
      {\texorpdfstring{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{#1}}}
}
\makeatother
```

The `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are not necessary and `\g@addto@macro` can be substituted with `\addto` if babel is loaded.

However this will also put the list of tables and list of figures in the table of contents; if you don't want this, just put the code

```
\renewcommand{\ChapS}[1]{\cleardoublepage
  \phantomsection\oldchap*{#1}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}
    {\texorpdfstring{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{#1}}}
```

after the `\listof...` commands.

One might also refrain from automatic insertion of unnumbered chapters in the toc and do the thing manually, say for the introduction:

```
\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{%
  \texorpdfstring{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Introduction}}{Introduction}%
}
```

Comment: This has the unfortunate side-effect of adding "Contents" to the table of contents (since the table of contents is a `\chapter*{}`).

Comment: @Alan: you're right, I modified the answer.

Comment: The second snippet of code seems to have no effect, no matter where it is placed. (I assume you meant *before* the `\listof` commands?)

Comment: This actually adds chapter* to the toc… but does not change the display of lines added with \addcontentsline. Apparently I missed something when I understood that \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Title} adds a chapter* line in the toc. This is really the behaviour I want to change…

Comment: @Alan: If I put the second snippet of code after `\listoftables` and `\listoffigures`, a subsequent `\chapter*{Introduction}` typesets a correctly formatted line in the table of contents.

Comment: @egreg I believe there is a typo in your last code sample ... `\texorpdfstring` takes two parameters, you have only one. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255990/82624

Comment: @StefanBraun You're right, a `}` was misplaced.