# Why am I receiving this package hyperref error?

Tags: hyperref

Error is:

```
Argument of \@secondoftwo has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.4 ...{$g(x)$} of the form \texorpdfstring{$ax$}}
```

MWE to get the error is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}  
\subsubsection{With \texorpdfstring{$g(x)$} of the form \texorpdfstring{$ax$}}
\end{document}
```

### Note:

I "solved" the error by placing a dot immediately after the `\texorpdfstring` command (why does it work?, I have no idea, I just was lucky), it's like if `\texorpdfstring` is waiting for an argument to end.

Solved error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}  
\subsubsection{With \texorpdfstring{$g(x)$} of the form \texorpdfstring{$ax$}.}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`hyperref` takes the text for bookmarks from the arguments of commands like `\section`, which can contain things like math, colors, or font changes, none of which will display in the pdf bookmarks as is.

Correct `\texorpdfstring` syntax is

```
\texorpdfstring{TEXstring}{PDFstring}
```

Comment: You will also see that in your "working" example in the question, the `o` in `of` is missing from the PDF, as `\texorpdfstring` grabs that as it's second argument.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That is right, not really noticeable though, thanks so much for making that point stand out.