# Math in subsection title and incorrect PDF sections' sidebar

Tags: math-mode, sectioning, bookmarks

I have a subsection named `\subsection{$Rp_{\widehat{Y},*}(\mathcal{P})$ has property bla and bla}`. I would like to keep this as title of my subsection, but it creates problems.

My code is the following.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath,amscd}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,left=30mm,right=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{accents} 
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[maxnames=99,style=alphabetic,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\begin{document}

\subsection{$Rp_{\widehat{Y},*}(\mathcal{P})$ has property bla and bla}

\end{document}
```

If I keep it like this, it compiles giving multiple warnings about "Token not allowed in a PDF string". In this case the main problem is that the sidebar index of sections of the outcome PDF carries "RpY"0362Y,*P bla and bla" instead of the correct title with the math.

Furthermore, if I replace `\widehat` by `\hat`, it gives the error "Tex capacity exceeded", and it does not compile.

If I replace `\subsection{$Rp_{\widehat{Y},*}(\mathcal{P})$ has property bla and bla}` (or the version with `\hat`) with `\subsection[just text]{$Rp_{\widehat{Y},*}(\mathcal{P})$ has property bla and bla}` then I get no error. On the other hand, I still don't get what I want in the sidebar, since I would really like the math to be there as well.

How can I have the PDF compiling correctly and carrying the right math on the sidebar as well?

Comment: You are limited in terms of what you can add to the bookmarks of a PDF, just because it's not (La)TeX. You should use `\texorpdfstring{<tex>}{<pdfstring>}` to distinguish between what you want in the document - `<tex>` - and what you want in the bookmark/index - `<pdfstring>`.

Comment: i know there has been at least one similar question, but i can't find it.  first of all, insert `\protect` before the commands `\widehat` and `\mathcal`; this may not be absolutely necessary, but it's not going to hurt.  second, math isn't really supported in bookmarks; you need to specify a `\texorpdfstring` to accommodate that; some useful information is given in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255990/579).

Comment: @Werner So there is no way the bookmark will displaythe math I want, right?

Comment: @Stefano: Most likely no, since the bookmarks are *text*-based.

Comment: @Werner Also, how does the use of `\texorpdfstring` differ from the use of `\subsection[put the words here]{put the title here}`? Thank you!

Comment: @Stefano: `\subsection[<toc>]{<title>}` puts `<toc>` in the ToC as well as the bookmarks. `\texorpdfstring{<tex>}{<pdfstring>}` allows to have something different in the `<toc>`, the `<doc>` and the bookmarks.